# How to format java.util.Date to desired String format?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

On android I need to format `java.util.Date` to String like this:

```
2015-09-10T09:17:26+02:00
```

I try to use SimpleDateFormat. I created this pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:Z` but you'll notice it doesn't format time zone part correctly. Colon is missing.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:Z").format(new Date());
// prints 2015-09-10T09:17:26+0200
```

Do you know solution to this problem?

Comment: It prints the colon for me.

Comment: if this is not working I would suggest you to get the date part in separate string and time part in separate string and then concatenate these two  strings. this would work , other wise I think you should show some code to use

Comment: do you mean `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:XXX`?

Comment: Using this pattern on android throws exception. Letter X is not supported. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

> Z/ZZ/ZZZ:-0800 ZZZZ:GMT-08:00 ZZZZZ:-08:00

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

So you need `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")`

Upd: it is supported since Android 4.3.
Question about it: [Using SimpleDateFormat's "ZZZZZ" (+03:00) for timezone before Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636917/using-simpledateformats-zzzzz-0300-for-timezone-before-android-4-3)

Comment: On android 5.x it works but on 4.x the colon is missing. Shieet.

Comment: Android is sure doing the best it can to piss off developers :D

Comment: @Egidijus Just checked the source code. Yes, it wasn't there from the beginning. Can't recommend it too :(